# Counting problem and probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

1. How many 10-letter words can be formed from the letters A, C, G, T?
2. For how many of these are no two consecutive letters the same?
3. How many 10-letter words are there of the form A...AC...CG...GT...T with all the As first, then the Cs, then the Gs, then the Ts, and at least on of each?

For this question I got part one to be $4^{10}$, and part two to be $4\cdot3^9$, and part three I need help. Would it be $10!$?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to choose the index of the first occurrence of each letter.

The index of the first occurrence of A is already known - it is the first index.

So you need to choose the remaining $3$ indexes out of the remaining $9$ options.

And the answer is of course $\binom{9}{3} = \frac{9!}{3!\cdot6!} = 84$.

Comment: what do you mean by index?

Comment: @BOB: The location of a letter in the string

Comment: It's a "Stars and Bars" problem.  You have four "boxes" to be filled with ten "balls", and must place at least one "ball" each "box".  All the "balls" in the first box become "A", those in the second become "C", and so on.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: @Graham Kemp: So is that aligned with my answer, or does it contradict it?

Comment: @barakmanos It's the same answer.  Where to put the 'bars' is the index of the first of each subsequent sequence of letters.

Comment: @Graham Kemp: Gotcha, thanks :)

Comment: @GrahamKemp and of course, instead of "stars and bars" you could call it "letters and gaps".

Answer (score 1):

As Barak Manos sais, "You just need to choose the index of the first occurrence of each letter."

Another way to look at is is that it's a "[Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)" problem.  You have four "boxes" to be filled with ten "balls", and must place at least one "ball" each "box".  All the "balls" in the first box become "A", those in the second become "C", and so on.

Take ten stars, and count the ways to insert three bars between them.

Such as "$\star\mid\star\,\star\mid\star\star\star\,\star\mid\star\star\star$" represents index 1,3,7: "$A_1CC_3GGGG_7TTT$".  Et cetera.

$$\text{Ways to select }3\text{ of }9\text{ spaces:}={9\choose 3}=\,^9C_3$$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of $10$ letters note that there are $9$ gaps between letters.  Some of them will be gaps between two of the same letter, e.g., AA, others will be between different letters, e.g., AC.  You need to choose the three gaps which are between different letters.  The number of possibilities is $C(9,3)$.

Alternatively, let $a,c,g,t$ be the number of As, Cs, Gs, Ts respectively.  Then you need the number of solutions of
$$a+c+g+t=10\quad\hbox{with}\quad a,c,g,t\ge1\ .$$
This is a standard counting problem and if you have learned how to do it you will find that you get the same answer as above.  If you have not yet learned it, just go with the above method.

Comment: answer would be 13C4

Comment: where is your error ?